# How to get real mouse position inside window's client on Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

When I use this code I have a wrong value of Y-mouse position. The returned value is (x, y+20).

```
int Height = int [[Window contentView] frame].size.height;

int x = (int)[(NSEvent *)event locationInWindow].x;

int y = Height - (int)[(NSEvent *)event locationInWindow].y;
```

I think that Height is the height of window :`title bar + rect client. I would like the real value of Height;

Comment: If you want to get the coordinates INSIDE the windows own coordinate system try bounds instead of frame

Comment: What do you mean by "real mouse position"? `[event locationInWindow]` is real.

Comment: @Pat_Morita bounds.origin is always equals to (0, 0) when I call [[Window] contentView] bounds]... Could you give me more information about this ?

Comment: That's why i asked if you need the coordinates INSIDE the window. Bounds uses the windows own coordinate system so bounds.origin will always be (0,0) which is the point at the bottom left of the window. If you use frame you will get the window's position according to the whole screen. Then (0,0) would be at the bottom left of your Screen. So please explain what you mean with "real mouse position" as @Willeke asked too.

Comment: @Pat_Morita I have a opengl program. I have only window with only one view inside. I would like the bounds of the main view inside the window to compute the mouse pointer position inside the main view

Comment: where does this code live?  in your window controller or in a view controller or -- hopefully -- in a custom NSView subclass (e.g. what you have your OpenGL code rendering from)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the coordinates to a view.

```
   - (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event
    {
        NSPoint locationInView = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow]
                                           fromView:yourView];
    }
```

Be sure to get some kind of event (in my example a mouse event). Make sure they are enabled.

```
[window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
```

Comment: "convertPoint fromView" with the "Window's contentView" is the good solution. Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't this be `[self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil]`? `self` is the view.